# activity_main cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse

Another newbie question.

```
package example.buttonedit;

import android.app.*;

import android.os.*;

import android.view.*;

import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){

            EditText edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

            String str=edit.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and the activity_main at the 4th line from the bottom is apparently causing the problem. I have edited a bit of the `activity_main.xml` as well.
please bear my jabberings since the site doesn't want me to post without writing more `details`.

Comment: Are you tried to clean project?

Comment: Apparently the file activity_main.xml is missing in the directory res/layout. 
Post the stacktrace (LogCat)

Comment: try to change the name of the menu file or example with activity_main_menu.xml

Comment: is your activity_main.xml file in the layout folder or in the menu folder?

Comment: @Krystian71115 I did clean the project but it didn't work

Comment: @Ivano donadi it's in the layout folder

Comment: If you have the menu with this same name change as the layout change it.

Comment: @KihyunKim then you can't use it as a menu resource. you have to create an xml file in the menu folder and set it int the menuinflater